# Get linear array of subform repeated values

Tags: jform, repeatable-field

So have a simple Field a user can enter some IDs in:

```
<field name="ids" type="subform" min="1" multiple="true" layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table" buttons="add,remove" groupByFieldset="false" label="IDs">
    <form>
        <fieldset name="section1" label="Section1">
            <field name="id" label="ID" min="0" type="number" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</field>
```

If i want fo get the IDs as a simple array. At the moment i do this:

```
$ids = array_column(json_decode(json_encode($this->params->get('ids')), TRUE), 'id');
```

That looks a bit weird, but i want to avoid using loops. Is there a framework friendly approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 7 `array_column()` supports passing an array of objects. You would only need to cast the data to array:

```
$ids = array_column((array) $this->params->get('ids'), 'id');
```

On older PHP versions you could cast to array and use `Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper::getColumn()` which supports passing array of objects on all PHP versions:

```
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

$ids = ArrayHelper::getColumn((array) $this->params->get('ids'), 'id');
```

Or, alternatively, use `Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper::fromObject()` to recursively convert the object to an array and then use `array_column()`:

```
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

$ids = array_column(ArrayHelper::fromObject($this->params->get('ids')), 'id');
```

I have not measured how performance compares to JSON encode/decode.

Comment: Sharky,  does `$this->params->get('ids')` return an object of objects?

Comment: Yes, repeatable subform normally stores data as an object of objects.